# unable to close private repo during docker build

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, ssh-keys

I’m running into a interesting problem…

I need to  clone a private git repo during a docker build. To do this, I’m passing my ssh keys from my local machine (mac pro) into the image using build-arg. Keys have been added to git. This process works locally.

I’m now trying to replicate this process with an ubuntu VM as the docker host. I’ve generated keys and am able to connect to git and clone from the repo from the ubuntu host. However, when passing the keys during the docker build it errors out.  docker image is `node:9` Anyone have an idea of what would cause this?

`npm ERR!
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128` (edited)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

created config file under ~/.ssh/

Host `<url>`

User git

StrictHOstKeyChecking no