# Why could git not clone private repo during docker build with '--mount=type=ssh'

Tags: git, docker, github, ssh, ssh-agent

I am trying to build a docker container with a private repo installed. I have no issue cloning the other repos that I require, but because one is private, it was suggested by a colleague to use `--mount=type=ssh`. I have skimmed a few articles, looked at a working example this colleague supplied (the example does not work for me but does for everyone else), and double checked the info in these questions:

[unable to close private repo during docker build [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998080/unable-to-close-private-repo-during-docker-build)

[Git clone private repo inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064227/git-clone-private-repo-inside-a-docker-container)

[git clone private repo with --mount=type=ssh does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75151480/git-clone-private-repo-with-mount-type-ssh-does-not-work)

But I have been unable to get it working. I have verified that the ssh agent is running:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 169089
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-.../agent.169088
ssh-add /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

And I believe it is configured properly because I can clone the repository on my host machine with no issue. When I attempt to clone this into a container during build however (using `docker build . -t test:latest` from the terminal in the folder with this dockerfile):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ARG proj_name=test
ARG test_user=test
ARG test_uid=1000
ARG test_gid=1000

# fix hashsum mismatch error during apt-get update/install
RUN echo $'Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;\n\
        Acquire::http::No-Cache true;\n\
        Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;\n'\
    >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90fix-hashsum-mismatch

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes \
        openssh-client git ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates

RUN groupadd --gid $test_gid $test_user && \
    useradd --create-home --gid $test_gid --uid $test_uid --shell /bin/bash --groups sudo $test_user && \
    echo "$test_user:test" | chpasswd && \
    echo "root:test" | chpasswd && \
    echo 'set -o vi' > /home/$test_user/.bashrc && \
    mkdir -p /home/$test_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/$test_user/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /home/$test_user/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    mkdir -p /opt/$proj_name/{source,build} && \
    chown -R $test_user:$test_user /opt/$proj_name /opt/$proj_name/{source,build} /home/$test_user/.ssh

USER $test_user

# LibApriltag (public)
RUN cd /opt/$proj_name && \
    git clone https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag.git

# Private repo
RUN --mount=type=ssh,uid=$test_uid cd /opt/$proj_name && \
    git clone git@github.com:<private_repo>.git
```

I get the ouput:

```
 > [stage-0 6/6] RUN --mount=type=ssh,uid=1000 cd /opt/test &&     git clone git@github.com:<private_repo>.git:                                                                               
#0 0.282 Cloning into '<private_repo>'...
#0 0.368 Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address <IP> to the list of known hosts.
#0 0.457 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
#0 0.458 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#0 0.458 
#0 0.458 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#0 0.458 and the repository exists.
```

I have tried a few various combinations of user/uid/ssh setup that made sense as potential culprits (although the coworkers example most closely resembled the above) to no avail, as well as disabled strict host key checking.
Past what I have done, anything more I try will be a shot in the dark as I am not very experienced with docker or git permission issues, so I am hoping someone can explain what else I may need be missing that could allow me to clone this private repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was a relatively simple fix, the argument `--ssh default` was missing from my docker build command. when running

```
docker build --ssh default . -t test:latest
```

the build was able to complete.